# code stops working after i create a setup using publish wizard

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

```
Public Sub bk()
        Try

            Dim strDatabasePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC.mdf")
            Dim strdbLogPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC_log.ldf")

            'Dim strDatabasePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(Application.UserAppDataPath, "LIC.mdf")
            'Dim strdbLogPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(Application.UserAppDataPath, "LIC_log.ldf")

            MsgBox(Application.UserAppDataPath)
            ' DB.Connection can be any valid SQLConnection which you might already be using in your application
            Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(LIC.My.Settings.LICConnectionString)
            Dim srvCon As New ServerConnection(con)

            Dim srv As Server = New Server(srvCon)
            MsgBox(srv.ToString)
            If srv.Databases.Contains(strDatabasePath) Then
                MsgBox("In If")

                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    MsgBox(con.State)
                    con.Close()

                End If
                MsgBox(con.State & " Is It True?")
                srv.KillAllProcesses(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC.mdf"))
                srv.DetachDatabase(strDatabasePath, True)

                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strDatabasePath, "c:\backup\LIC.mdf", True)

                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strdbLogPath, "c:\backup\LIC_log.ldf", True)

                MessageBox.Show("Backup taken successfully")

            End If

            srvCon.Disconnect()

            con.Open()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured : " & ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

I am using the given code to copy my database files...it works like a charm in debug mode but as soon as i
 create a setup
...it stops working...the error is **"Database Detach Failed"** ...
i tried checking the code line by line and found that the code 
does not enter  the IF block..
.i have no idea why...can i get some help on this??

Comment: what happened to stackoverflow?? Not a single reply??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the database path instead of the database name. You can use this code to solve the problem:

```
Public Sub bk()
    Try
        ''# DB.Connection can be any valid SQLConnection which you might already be using in your application
        Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(LIC.My.Settings.LICConnectionString)
            Dim srvCon As New ServerConnection(con)
            Dim srv As Server = New Server(srvCon)

            If srv.Databases.Contains(con.Database) Then
                srv.KillAllProcesses(con.Database)

                srv.DetachDatabase(con.Database, True)

                System.IO.File.Copy(srv.MasterDBPath, "c:\backup\LIC.mdf", True)
                System.IO.File.Copy(srv.MasterDBLogPath, "c:\backup\LIC_log.ldf", True)

                MessageBox.Show("Backup taken successfully")
            End If
            srvCon.Disconnect()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occured : " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```